# Android Webview loading responsive-design site, but webview is not resizing correctly

Tags: android, web-applications, webview, responsive-design, viewport

I have read all of the related questions to this, and all recommendations are implemented in my code as you can see, but the site still is not rendering correctly. I am fairly certain it has to do with device dpi. The device I am testing with is a Google Nexus 7 with a xhdpi, here are its specs:

> 7.02" 1920x1200 HD display (323 ppi); 1080p HD IPS

The page should automatically switch to single column view, but instead displays as if on a very large screen (thus making buttons too small). Here is code:

Site:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android App");
    webView.setInitialScale(30);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WHMWebViewClient(this));

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.responsive_website.com");
}
```

Android 4.3

As I am fairly sure it is dpi related (the physical screen should show the mobile layout, but the dpi makes the site think it isn't a mobile screen), what options do I have? My first preference would be to make adjustments device-side since I am developing the app for an existing site I don't own. If this isn't possible, what adjustments would need to be made in the site? Note that browsers such as Chrome and FFox are able to display the site properly.

Comment: Is your webview a standard WebView or a WHM Client?

Comment: standard. WHMWebViewClient simply tells the webview to override url load for the site pages and facebook (thus everything else will be opened in system browser).

Comment: Any solution found? I am also searching for same thing but no help